# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio attribute case sensitivity

Tags: sql-server

We have a table with userId field defined as a unique identifier, GUID. we are using Microsoft SQL Server studio to query our users and modify information. We are facing a problem that when we "Select" rows, the result comes back with uppercase "userId" and when we choose to "Edit" the result comes back with lowercase "userId"

- is there a way we can do a select on the table and retrieve EXACTLY how the fields were entered, including the userId's case sensitivity?

SELECT top X rows:
[image: Select TOP X Rows]
EDIT top X rows:
[image: EDIT TOP X Rows]

Comment: Interesting observation!  Is there a problem/concern though?  If you do not have case sensitive collation, i don't think it matters.

Comment: I would avoid using the "Edit top rows" functionality anyway. There are a number of problems with it. It can deadlock among a few other unpleasant challenges. This could be another in the list of reasons to just write t-sql in the SSMS query window. I will have to try this out on a case sensitive database and see what happens.

Comment: I've got a database with Latin1_General_CS_AS collation.  `select 1 where cast('950dbbf0-5fcb-4db7-815f-39cbd4cec2c0' as uniqueidentifier) = CAST('950DBBF0-5FCB-4DB7-815F-39CBD4CEC2C0' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)` returns a row.  It shouldn't matter unless it's another issue with "Edit top rows".

Comment: I just tried this on a CS database and it works just fine. Even the "Edit top rows" works just fine, even if the guid column is the primary key.

Comment: Right but it doesn't actually matter because the value is implicitly cast to a guid and it doesn't make any difference if the string representations are upper or lower.

Comment: I get it. It is the visual representation in SSMS. But there is no issue here. Are you having an issue as a result of this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94755/discussion-between-sarah-a-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 1):

In your situation think of your problem as “Client Code” not sql values on the server.
The guid values are binary 128 bit fields in the database.   The query result windows or any other string representation may or may not upshift the string hex values so that we humans can see the values.

You may be relying on the Case sensitivity in your client code as you may be relying on an implied or explicit guid to sting cast.  Or possibly a string to guid cast.

I see this all the time when xml or file feeds may Upshift or Lower the string representation of values such that case sensitive string compare in C# .NET fail.  I have never seen the string Upper or Lower or formal guid representation matter to SQL Server, it has always cast or converted properly or sometimes with a little cast helper.

The problem, if there was one, was in the client code always.

The .NET guid type can be very useful when writing or evaluating string representations of guids.  In particular the ToString Formatter in the guid type has formats like “N”  “D”  “B” etc. that can give you exactly what you want at runtime if you need that exact string type of manipulation.

I have had some luck standardizing on “N” 32 hex digits all upper case with no formatting for file string guid representations.    It just seems to work everywhere at the file level.